# Finding text within text delimited by new line character

Tags: mysql, string, string-search

I am trying to find text within text using MySQL.  I have a field of values that is somewhat unstructured, but the data entry fortunately is delimited by new lines.  I'm trying to see if I can pull the value for "Education", which would be basically a substring that starts after "Education:" and ends with \n new line character in data below:

```
'Children:  5
Education:  College
Employment: Homemaker
Marital Status: Married'
```

I've looked at the MID function, but since the values for education vary, the length isn't standard. I have searched MySQL string functions, and I have not found a solution that will allow me to search between two positions, including one that is defined by a regex character -- the REGEX simply provides a match, not a position.

```
SELECT id,MID(value,POSITION('Education:' IN value),30) 
FROM client_data
```

the code performed as expected, but due to fixed length rather than position of \n new line character, results either truncated or included extra characters from subsequent text.

I'm guessing there is a way to do this that I'm just not finding.

Comment: Each field is followed by a new line character, so there would be a new line character for example between "5" and "Education", "College and "Employment", etc. in the example provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEXP_SUBSTR to get actual the string that matched the regular expression:

```sql
REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '^Education:.*', 1, 1, 'm')
```

This gets you the `Education line`. Then you just need to extract the part after the `:` from that string:

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '^Education:.*', 1, 1, 'm'),
  '^Education:', '')
```

Comment: That looks great.  I get the error that REGEXP_SUBSTR does not exist. I checked, and it looks like I'm on MySQL 5.6, which does not appear to support this function.